# How to configure security groups when connecting to mongodb between AWS ec2 instances?

Tags: mongodb, security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have one ec2 instance with mongodb (called ec2-mongo) with the security group, sg-mongodb-server. And I am trying to connect to mongodb via another ec2 instance (called ec2-connect) with the security group, sg-connect. I want to set the rules to allow for traffic between the two security groups without referring to specific IP Addresses. How can I do this?

I can connect to mongo when my security groups are set up as follows (so there is nothing wrong with the servers as far as I know). Outbound is set to all:

**sg-mongodb-server**:

```
Inbound:
Port    Source
22      my_ip
27017   ip_of_ec2-connect
```

**sg-connect**:

```
Inbound:
Port    Source
22      my_ip
27017   ip_of_ec2-mongo
```

but when I try to use security groups instead of IP Addresses I can't connect to mongodb.

**sg-mongodb-server**:

```
Inbound:
Port    Source
22      my_ip
27017   sg-connect
```

**sg-connect**:

```
Inbound:
Port    Source
22      my_ip
27017   sg-mongodb-server
```

Error message when trying to connect:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.3
connecting to: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/test
2016-02-19T18:24:09.245+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:27017 after 5000 milliseconds, giving up.
2016-02-19T18:24:09.245+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:226:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for security group references to work, you need to connect to your MongoDB from the EC2 instance by the MongoDB server's **private** IP address, not it's public IP address.

If you are using the public IP address (or the DNS name is resolving to the public IP address), then the connection will leave your VPC and re-enter, thus appearing to originate from the outside world.

By using the private IP address, then it can tell that it's coming from your security group.